# How can I find a second value in an array

Tags: php

I have an long Array like this. In this array there is some times a second "Filiale".

```
First part:

array(7) {
  ["Barcode"]=>         string(12) "010307910147"
  ["Ean"]=>             NULL
  ["GesamtBestand"]=>   int(1)
  ["Groessengang"]=>    string(1) "I"
  ["FilialBestand"]=>   array(1) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
                ["Filiale"]=>   int(1)
                ["Menge"]=>     int(1)
        }
  }
  ["Prime"]=>           bool(true)
  ["EbayPlus"]=>        bool(false)
}


Second part:
array(7) {
  ["Barcode"]=>         string(12) "010307910149"
  ["Ean"]=>             NULL
  ["GesamtBestand"]=>   int(1)
  ["Groessengang"]=>    string(1) "I"
  ["FilialBestand"]=>   array(1) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
                ["Filiale"]=>   int(1)
                ["Menge"]=>     int(1)
        }
        [1]=> array(2) {
                ["Filiale"]=>   int(1)
                ["Menge"]=>     int(1)
        }
  }
  ["Prime"]=>           bool(true)
  ["EbayPlus"]=>        bool(false)
}
```

How can I check if this second "Filiale" exists: ?

```
        [1]=> array(2) {
                ["Filiale"]=>   int(1)
                ["Menge"]=>     int(1)
        }
```

I hope someone helps the newcomer...

Thanks.

This is my Script:

```
<?php
$json_filename = "GetChangesSince.json";
$ipos_filename = "data.csv";

$fp = fopen($json_filename, "w");
$fpos = fopen($ipos_filename, "w");

$contents = curlGetData($url, $login, $agent);

// Schreibe Daten in Datei
fwrite($fp, $contents);
fclose($fp); 

$jsonfile = file_get_contents($json_filename);
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile,true);

$csvdata = "";
$head = "Barcode;Bestand;Menge;";
$csvdata .= $head."\r\n";

foreach($jsonarray as $k=>$alldata) 
{

   foreach($alldata["FilialBestand"] as $idx => $FilialBestand) 
   {
   $csvdata .= $alldata['Barcode'].';'.$alldata['GesamtBestand'].';'.$FilialBestand['Menge']."\r\n";
   }
}   

fwrite($fpos, $csvdata); 
fclose($fpos); 


 ?>
```

......................................
......................................

How can I check if the Filiale is second time there?

Comment: First step is to loop. Second is to try accessing `Filiale` with an isset check in `['FilialBestand']['Filiale']`.

Comment: I loop it via foreach($jsonarray as $k=>$alldata)  then I make a foreach($alldata["FilialBestand"] as $idx => $FilialBestand). How can I check if the Filiale exists more than one time?

Comment: Let's say if it exists, what would you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take an array as 2d array 
`array[“mykey”][1]`
however if it’s not constant you can check size first for to do that

```
<?php
 if(sizeOf($my_array[“mykey”]) > 1) { 
   foreach($my_array[“mykey”] as $value){ 
     echo $value;
   }
 } ?>
```